# Exporting generated point cloud to Unreal with color data

Tags: shaders, uv-image-editor, vertex-colors, unreal-engine, point-clouds

I'm an art student from Paris, used to work with blender and pointclouds, and I have a ploblem that I can't seem to be able to solve.

My workflow is (most of the time) what follows :
Modeling mesh > procedural shading > UV unwrap > baking all materials into one single png > Geo-nodes to get a point cloud (something like distribute points on faces > set point radius >set material with a store named attribute color+points plugged into my baked png itself plugged into the UV vector, with the material beeing a diffuse or principled shader with the attribute as a color).
That beeing said, this works all the time and Im used to troubleshoot this.
Now my problem is that I need for a specific project to export this PC into Unreal (Yeah... ).
So my solution was to :
-Convert my points to vertex, then export to .obj, then import in CloudCompare (OS and great tool) for exporting to .las, as Unreal can read it with LiDAR plugin.
-OR exporting it in .ply BUT This doesn't seems like working with only vertex and no faces objects so gaves me an empty file. Anyway I tried with my first modelled object and I can get a point cloud file with only the vertex of the faces, but still have the same problem : COLOR DATA.

No that I explain it as well as I can, my problem is color data : how can I get the vertex cloud to have my baked UV mapped image as vertex color ? As for now it's only the material that contains this data ?

I hope someone kind could at least lead me to something else to try... Anyway if you read this far thank you so much ! <3

---

Kilian.